# web service .exe crashing on server

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created just a simple web service as a console application. It works fine on my dev machine and even on one of my servers. when I installed it on my production server I keep catching this error

the error that I am catching says

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {BF97F9A2-A475-4F26-9B
5B-3A14F02D9824} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

My dev machine is 32 bit windows 7. The Server that it works on is server 2008 64bit, the server that is DOES NOT work on is also server 2008 64 bit.

any idea how to resolve this?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the COM component you are accessing is registered.

Comment: Maybe this sounds dumb but I don't know what com component is is trying to access. How can I check this and register it?

Comment: not dumb at all.  Look at your references and see if you have any "Interop" references.  Did you reference any non-GAC assemblies as part of your application?  The only reference to the CLSID I found on the net refers to Intuit / Quickbooks... are you using that at all?

Comment: Yes I am using A quickbooks dll. I have it set to copy local= true in my references as well. What else do I need to do?

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to install the SDK on this server. I did not know it had been installed on the working server already by the sys admin. I am good now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/88a6ea68-f476-4231-822f-27fabe59f458/) on social.msdn:

> The problem was simply that the 3rd party dll required other dlls that were not on the system. So I installed the required (other) dlls and everything is fine.

Check that everything your service needs is properly installed on the server.